# mechanical iris cloth problem

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I’m working on a mechanical iris.

What I want is a sort of rubber sleave/cover over the leaves of the mechanical iris so you can’t see the leaves.

[image]

I’m using a cloth simulation to get the mesh reacting on the leaves of the mechanical iris. Problem is that I can’t figure out the right setting for the cloth simulation, it doesn’t work properly in any option I tried.

•   All the leaves are collisions

•   On the sleave mesh I applied a cloth physic with this settings

[image: setting]

[image]

Is there somebody who knows how to fix this problem or knows a other method do achieve the same result?

Comment: How this thing should look like? So https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGhy9.gif ?

Comment: Yes kinda like that, how did you achieve that?

Comment: I've increased the *Shrink* value a little bit and used the *Rubber* preset for the cloth physics

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. Can you explane it al littlebit more? I dont know exactly what you mean with the Shrink value. And how you make to gape close and open

Comment: It's in the *Cloth* simulation settings, where you can use the *Shape > Shrinking Factor* value (+/-) to tighten or widen the cloth. The cloth settings of the *Rubber* preset do make the gape close and open but when I've modeled the mechanics as you did I had to give it a little Shrink Factor. Maybe my cloth mesh was bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a lazily modeled mockup because I can no longer find my first detailed model. It's a disc with *Collision* physics and a *Shapekey* that reduces the hole in the center. A torus with a *Cloth* physics overlaps it. There is a short animation that switches between the shape keys.

I've turned off *Gravity*, and increased the *Shape > Shrinking Factor* a little (it's not needed for this model but for the first one). Here is the initial state:
[image: open state]

Then used the *Rubber* preset for the *Cloth* settings and ran the animation. (The presets are in the "hamburger menu" right next to the *Cloth* section.) And I've given the *Cloth* settings some *Pressure* to dampen the torus a bit and make it wobble less when the "iris" opens again.
[image: closed state]

Here's a test with the previous detailed model. It looked like as shown above in the question's first screenshot. The open/close mechanic made the cloth spin around.
[image: closed state]